# ar_pose message subscriber

Tags: ros, ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to write a simple subscriber in order to read the messages published by ar_pose (as in the example 4.4 of http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) but I am having some trouble in finding how to import in my c++ code the definition of the message used. In particular I can't find a way to import the definition of ar_pose::ARMarker.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28611/ar_pose-message-subscriber/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You can include these headers:

```
#include <ar_pose/ARMarker.h>
```

or

```
#include <ar_pose/ARMarkers.h>
```

depending if you want to work with a single or multiple markers.

The bag files in the ar_pose page are old, and have to be fixed with a command `rosbag fix`, there is also a problem with the frame transformations (check [ar_pose track](http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/trac/ticket/17)), therefore I would recommend you to print a marker and test it with an USB camera or other. I think it will be easier.
regards.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2012-02-29**:
That was exactly what I was trying, and for some unknown reason it wasn't working. Now evrything is ok, thank you!